# var hoisting and scope availability

Tags: javascript

As we know `var` declarations get hoisted but with `undefined` value:

```
console.log(a); // undefined

var a = 2
```

## But this code is different:

```
function foo() {
    console.log(a); 
}

function bar() {
    var a = 3;
    foo();
}

var a = 2;

bar(); // 2
```

Wy does it log `2` instead of `undefined` ?

Why `var a`'s value became magically accessible before it's declaration ?

Comment: Because you called `foo()` *after* you initialized the variable.

Comment: It's the order of execution that matters, not the lexical order.

Comment: Btw, `const` and `let` variables are also hoisted, you just get an error when you try to use them before initialization.

Answer (score 1):

You're calling `bar()` after you initialize the variable, so it's not `undefined` any more.

See this simpler example:

```js
function foo() {
    console.log(a); 
}

foo(); // a is not yet initialized, prints undefined

var a = 2;

foo(); // a is now initialized, prints 2
```

Hoisting just makes the variable declaration available (so you don't get an "Undefined variable" error). The initialization is just an assignment that happens in the normal order.